# java ClassNotFoundException in jar files

Tags: java

I'm trying to run a java file which is in the /lib/jarfile.jar jar file in the path "il/co/codeguru/corewars8086/CoreWarsEngine" with this command in linux:

```
java -cp lib/jarfile.jar il.co.codeguru.corewars8086.CoreWarsEngine
```

but I get this error message:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class il.co.codeguru.corewars8086.CoreWarsEngine
```

I read I little bit about classpathes in java but i still don't know what is wrong with what I did...

this is the content of CoreWarsEngine

```
package il.co.codeguru.corewars8086;

import il.co.codeguru.corewars8086.gui.CompetitionWindow;

import java.io.IOException;

public class CoreWarsEngine
{
    public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        CompetitionWindow c = new CompetitionWindow();
        c.setVisible(true);
        c.pack();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not a lot to go on here, you should upload a minimum reproducible example

Comment: Looks like `CoreWarsEngine` doesn't have a `main` method

Comment: Try without "throws IOException" in main() method prototype?

Comment: (1) the file for that class should be `il/co/codeguru/codewars8086/CoreWarsEngine.class` not what you said (2) your text says `/lib/jarfile.jar` but your command uses `lib/jarfile.jar` -- these are NOT the same; which is correct? @MadProgrammer: if that were the (only) problem it would produce a very different error message

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the jar file exists at the location you expect it to be and matches the jar file name in the command. This may seam silly, but java that I have, 11 AdoptOpenJDK does not complain that it did not find the jar file:

```
java -cp nonexistingfile.jar il.co.codeguru.corewars8086.CoreWarsEngine
Error: Could not find or load main class il.co.codeguru.corewars8086.CoreWarsEngine
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: il.co.codeguru.corewars8086.CoreWarsEngine
```

Second make sure the jar contains the class you are trying to start. I have stumbled on at least one `corewars8086` download on the net that does not have the `CoreWarsEngine` class.

If you got the sources from [GitHub/codeguru-il/corewars8086](https://github.com/codeguru-il/corewars8086) then you need maven to build it. The resulting jar will be in `target/corewars8086-4.0.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar`. Or if you build it a different way then you need to figure out where the result jar will be and what is the name.

I managed to run it from the sources of the above repo[image]